# EU Blue Card Application with BA Degree for Software Developer

Tags: germany, education, visa

I hope everyone is doing well and healthy. 
I have a query regarding the Blue Card Application. Recently I have received a Job offer from a German company with a salary of Euro 58K, and I have only a BA degree from Indian University along with six years of IT work experience. The company is preparing the Contract and asking me to go for the EU blue card visa appointment. I am worried about this part. Is there any possibility to get  National Visa for Blue card with my BA degree as a Software Developer. If anyone familiar with the situation or have any idea about this scenario, please share with me. I will be pleased to hear about it.

Comment: Why are you are worried about going to the EU blue card visa appointment? Would you also need an appointment for a  National Visa for Blue card ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [BAMF](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/Arbeiten/BuergerDrittstaat/BlaueKarte/blaue-karte-node.html;jsessionid=715B7325EFB4D25A21468693D6F2BA1F.1_cid368)

> The EU Blue Card is a residence permit which, when issued for the
>   first time, is valid for a maximum of four years. It is issued subject
>   to the following conditions:
>
> - a German or recognised foreign or comparable foreign higher
>     educational qualification
> - submission of an employment contract or a
>     binding job offer
> - as a matter of principle proof of a minimum annual
>     gross salary of 53,600 Euro.
>
>   - Exception: A lower salary threshold of 41,808 Euro is applied for EU
>       Blue Cards issued to scientists, mathematicians and engineers, as well
>       as to doctors and IT specialists.
> - restricted to a maximum of four years when first issued.
>
>   - Exception: If the employment contract is shorter than four years, the
>       residence title is issued for a period that is limited to the term of
>       the employment contract, plus three months.
>
> Holders of an EU Blue Card are to be issued with an unlimited
>   settlement permit if:
>
> - they have held their employment as a highly-qualified person for more
>     than 33 months,
> - they can demonstrate that they have made obligatory
>     contributions in this period or show other proof of expenditure to
>     obtain an entitlement to insurance benefits which are comparable to
>     those from statutory pensions insurance, and
> - the other prerequisites
>     generally necessary for issuing a settlement permit are met.
> - If the
>     holder of the EU Blue Card has an adequate knowledge of German (level
>     B1), the settlement permit is issued earlier, namely after 21 months.

It looks like you have
 - BA Software Engineering (recognised foreign or comparable foreign higher educational qualification)
 - A job offer,
 - A Salary of €58.000 (Above the min €53.600)

You are entitled to a Blue Card for 4 years. If you keep your employment for 3 years (33 months), pay into your employee contributions, and a B1 in German you will be able to get permanent residence.

Comment: Not sure that it is a BA in software engineering I think its an arts Degree which why the OP is worried.

Comment: Dean's answer makes sense to get a blue card with the existing offer, but I am worried about with my BA degree only. BA in India is a three years bachelor degree in arts. Additionally, I know the A2 level of German and doing Master Degree in Computer Science through Distance mode which will take one more year to award the degree. So without a technical degree may I can proceed my Visa?

Comment: You have a Bachelor Degree which is Germany is accepted as a "recognised foreign [...] higher educational qualification". This solves point 1. You have an employment contract. This solves point 2. You have a minimum annual gross salary above 53.600€ (which is the point where you start to pay maximum taxes btw.). This solves point 3. Point 4 is just an info that it is restricted to 4 years.

In other words: You fulfill all requirements. It should in no way matter that your degree is for another field.

Comment: Also the simplest thing with basically everything regarding such matters in my experience is to talk to them about it. You are definitely not the first person to be in this situation - if you are polite and ask nicely they will surely help you.